# How can I view special characters in SQL Server 2012 Management Studio grid view?

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms

In a SQL Server 2012 database, I have a log table where I log SQL queries executed by a VB.NET application.

The field is defined as `nvarchar(MAX)`

In Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, when I go to the table and do "Edit All Rows", 
on one line I see spaces in the end of the text [image: ScreenShot 1]

But when I enter my cursor in the line to edit it (not touching anything, before I even start editing), the spaces disappear (along with the trailing quote) [image: Screenshot 2]

And when I go to New Query and execute the same query

```
SELECT LOGID, LogDate, SqlLog 
FROM ezber_SQL_LOG 
WHERE (LOGID = 1604))
```

I get the result without the spaces and the trailing quote:

[image: Screenshot 3]

So my guess is that there are special characters in the data (line breaks, tabs or something like that), but how can I find out for sure and know what they are?

Comment: If you're only looking at a single row, try a query window with results to text instead of results to grid.

Comment: Results to text was giving me the same result as Results to Grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the answer in following post: (the one with pictures).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897950/how-do-you-view-all-text-from-an-ntext-or-nvarcharmax-in-ssms/11900246#11900246

You need "copy current cell 1:1", or you can use notepad++ as visualizer:

Comment: I tried it and it fact I was able to find what I was looking for by using  "open cell contents in external text editor (notepad++ or notepad) using "Cell visualizers" feature". 
Notepad++ shows "NUL" characters where the text cuts in the results grid/text

Comment: Yepp ! You can even use hex editor (or Hex plugin for notepad++) to see all data as HEX. Happy that it helped ! Read full features list and I am sure this will be not the only feature you will like ;)

Answer (score 4):

I found [viewing the data as binary](https://www.databasejournal.com/tips/displaying-and-removing-unprintable-hexadecimal-characters-from-sql-server-data.html) was the way to go for me:

```
SELECT @String as MyString, CAST(@String as varbinary(max)) MyString_In_Hexidecimal;
```

I found [an ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) then helped decipher what was in the string.